# Compressed Archive Logs in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, database-administration

It is very Noob question about compressing Archive Logs in PostgreSQL 10.

My situation.

- Ubuntu 18
- postgresql 10
- pg_wal - 10Gb
- path - `/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/pg_wal/`

I have a big pg_wal folder right now it is 10 Gg and growing. In pg_wal I saw a very large number journal of files capacity 16mb.
Right now I don't have a capacity.

I read the [postgresql manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/continuous-archiving.html) 25.3.6.2 (gzip)

and I saw two command it is

```
archive_command = 'gzip < %p > /var/lib/pgsql/archive/%f'
restore_command = 'gunzip < /mnt/server/archivedir/%f > %p'
```

Can I use the path `/var/lib/postgresql/10/main/pg_wal/`
in archive_command?

```
archive_command = 'gzip <%p> /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/pg_wal/%f'.
restore_command = ''gunzip < /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/pg_wal/%f > %p'
```

Is it a possible or it is stupid idea?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My error I think it is typical junior error. I have: archive_mode = on. But don't write a archive_command. Right now I think what need to do.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only archive the WAL segments to a different destination.

First, remove whatever obstacle kept the WAL segments from being deleted:

- failing `archive_command` (check `pg_stat_archiver`)
- abandoned replication slot (check `pg_replication_slots`)
- high `wal_keep_segments`

Do not manually remove or modify files in `pg_wal`.

Comment: Prepared transaction doesn't belong on that list.  It doesn't block WAL archival, it blocks vacuum clean up.